# Rails 4: Link tag that creates a record doesn't work with strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'd like to create a new post simply by clicking a link. When I create this button, I get an error (below):

HTML:

```
<%= link_to 'Create That Post', {
    controller: 'posts',
    action: 'create',
    user_id: '123',
    title: 'Test Create a Post'
  },
  method: 'post',
  class: "btn btn-sm btn-success instagramBtn",
  id: "createPostBtn"
%>
```

Error:

param is missing or the value is empty: post

```
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(  # Error points to this line.
      :title, 
      :description, 
      :user_id
```

This error seems reasonable, since the params being passed in are not in a `post` hash, like `post[title]`. Am I setting up the params wrong when I do my `<%= link_to ... %>`?

Comment: I didn't try, but changing the post attribute keys like this: `user_id:` -> `'post[user_id]' =>` should work

Comment: show us the params in the server log please.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, give an explanation so the author can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using the post params and the params can't change, don't use strong params. Just catch the content of the params you need and create the post.

```
def new_post_from_button
  @post = Post.create(user_id: params[:user_id], title: params[:title])
end
```

As an alternative just remove the .require from the permits method.

```
private

def fixed_strong_params
  params.permit(:user_id, :title)
end
```